# ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageDataGenerator' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagedatagenerator

ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageDataGenerator' from 'keras.preprocessing.image' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image/**init**.py)

Occurred when running in Kaggle. The issue is not present when running in google collab

It should ideally run without throwing any error

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Tried this and working as expected:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also note this is now depreciated, reference https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator "Deprecated: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator is not recommended for new code. Prefer loading images with tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory and transforming the output"

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me and then I change it and its working!

for keras-3.0.5 & tensorflow-2.16.1 the way for importing ImageDataGenerator is

`from keras.src.legacy.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`